# Visualizing what part of the surface is integrated by surface integral

Tags: integration, conic-sections, surfaces, surface-integrals, visualization

> I'm trying to draw the region of the surface area of the cylinder, $x^2+y^2 \le 2x$, limited
>   by the cone $z=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$ and the plane $z=0$ . I know that
>   the cylinder's center is at $(1,0)$
>   $x^2+y^2\leq2x$ can be rewritten as $(x-1)^2+y^2\leq1$: a closed circle with center
>   $(1,0)$ and radius $1$.
>
> First parametrise by setting $x-1=\cos \theta$, $y=\sin \theta$
>
> This gives $z=\sqrt{2x}=\sqrt{2(\cos \theta+1)}$.
>
> We can now imagine the cylinder being unwrapped, so that the area is:
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2(\cos \theta+1)} d\theta$$

I have no idea how to visualize the part of the cylinder $x^2+y^2 \le 2x$ limited
by the cone $z=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$ and the plane $z=0$.

Trying to visualize, I'm guessing that the surface area given by the integral is the area

> $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2(\cos \theta+1)} d\theta$$

of a conic section?

I don’t think the cylinder is bounded above which is a problem.

Comment: Is surface area a part of the surface $ z=\sqrt{2x}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cylinder is tangent to the $y$ axes in $(0,0)$, which is the cone vertex.    Of the cone you are considering the upper part $0 \le z$.
The portion of cylinder below that is a sort of "nail".

Working in cylindrical coordinates $(r, \phi, z)$ centered at $(1,0,0)$,
the point $(r=1, -\pi < \phi \le \pi, 0)$ will be distant $\sqrt{(1+cos\phi)^2+sin^2\phi}$ from the origin, and the cone will be at the same distance above it.

Along the base circle $dl=d\phi$ and the elementary surface is $dA= \sqrt{(1+cos\phi)^2+sin^2\phi}\;d\phi$.

[image: Cone_Cyl_1]

Can you continue from here ?

Comment: No, I still cant visualize whats going on

Comment: I can’t see how the region is bounded above. Of course the region is bounded below by z=0.

Comment: Can you draw a picture?

Comment: Can you visualize a upward circular cone with vertex in the origin ? and $45^\circ$ aperture ? a sort of big icecream ? Can you visualize to lay on the ground a metal ring of radius $1$, and push it to touch the vertex ?  Can you then visualize to raise from the circle a vertical curtain / fence till touching the cone above ? that starts at $0$ at the vertex, goes gradually increasing untill you reach the point on the ring diametrically opposite to the vertex, which is distant $2$ from the vertex, and so where the curtain reaches its max height = $2$? and symmetrically for the other half ?

Comment: Are we pushing the metal ring of radius 1 up in the z-direction? Is the metal ring of radius one only touching the vertex only at one point?

Comment: we are putting on the ring some dozens of Laser lights, pointing vertically, till they hit the cone (and absorbed there because it is black): what's the shape of the light curtain ?

Comment: is the picture clarifying your doubts ?

Comment: Is the shape parabolic?

Comment: when stretched, it looks much like a parabola, but it is not exactly that , the height follows the function given for $dA$ above, which is the same as the one you already found. By the way, the final result of the integral is $S=8$.